# Store function variable in ASM functions in Delphi

Tags: delphi, assembly, basm

How can I properly store `n` in functions like the following one ? Because of value in `n` changes for some reason after I use it once.

```
function Test(n: Integer): Byte;
asm
  mov eax, n
  add eax, eax
  add eax, n
  mov ecx, eax
  mov ebx, eax
  mov ecx, n
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument to the function, `n`, is stored in `eax`, so your line

```
mov eax, n
```

is highly strange (move `n` to `n`). Also, if you change `eax`, you change `n`.

You could save the argument for future use (since you likely need to alter `eax`):

```
var
  tempN: integer;
asm
  mov tempN, eax
```

Also, IIRC, you must *not* change the value of `ebx` when writing inline ASM. Hence, you need to surround your code by `push ebx` and `pop ebx`.

Comment: but where I could store some extra values? except stack

Comment: @DanilGholtsman: You are free to use the registers any way you want, as long as you restore those that must be restored before you 'return'. (And the heap is all yours.)